# Какая служба windows создает пакеты ethernet

Tags: windows, веб-служба, трафик, пакеты

Всем, привет!
Какая служба windows создает пакеты ethernet? Анализатор трафика перехватывает пакеты идут из ос на сетевую карту и обратно. Где конкретно происходит преобразование сообщения или запроса в пакет?

Comment: В ядре, наверное?

Comment: Точно службу не скажу, т.к. службы это другое. Но примерно в механизме winsock. Т.е. это набор функций для обработки сетевых данных. winsock.dll(windows) работает с сетевой картой через драйвера сетевой карты. ЯП такие как Си, Си++ используют библиотеку winsock, в которой описаны связи с функциями Windows, работающими с сетью. А драйвера сетевых карт производят физическую отправку данных, железом сетевухи.

Comment: Наверно вы про Windows Hooks спрашиваете?. https://habr.com/ru/companies/icl_group/articles/324718/

Comment: То есть каждое сетевое приложение будь то браузер или какой-нибудь зум, имеет в себе функции(методы) винсока и самостоятельно уже создает пакеты, которые попадают на сетевой адаптер?

Comment: Эм, зачем? Методы винсока лежат не в приложении, а в winsock.dll (и скорее всего это просто обёртка над системными вызовами ядра)

Comment: И да, пакеты не могут попадать из приложения в сетевой адаптер, потому что было бы крайне опасно, если бы приложения могли так делать и пихали бы в сетевуху вредоносные пакеты. Что ещё раз намекает на то, что скорее всего пакеты делаются в ядре

Comment: Всем большое спасибо!